# How to sound iPhone's default shutter sound

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, avfoundation

Currently, I use AVFoundation's AVCaptureVideoDataOutput to create a camera application.

It is a specification that I tap the shooting button and save the necessary frame as a still image on the camera roll.

(I do not save movies.)

About the shutter sound of the iPhone, I ask you a question.

・Question

What kind of coding should I do in order to sound the iPhone's default shutter sound?

At first, I created a camera application without shutter sound using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.

Next, I would like to create a camera with shutter sound using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.

I do not know how to sound the iPhone's default shutter sound while using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.

Is there a way to forcibly sound the iPhone's default shutter sound?

■Supplement

xcode8.3.3

swift3.1

Deployment Target:10.2

I'd like to implement AVCaptureVideoDataOutput because I want to implement both movie shooting and still shooting in the future.

Comment: Because I am using AVCaptureVideoDataOutput, iPhone's default shutter sound does not sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

use this:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1108);
```

You can check all full sounds here:

[Sounds](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices)

For a custom sound:

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Name of your audio file" 
                                                      ofType:@"type of your audio file example: mp3"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[audioPlayer play];
```

Make sure you import

`<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`